# Jquery load url

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two tabs as tab1 and tab2, These 2 are calling same function `uploadfile()` or same url then how refresh individual tabs content when we upload a image
when we upload a image its automatically added to div before closing div

Comment: I'm sorry... what are you asking? And where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

i believe both tabs have unique id.

```
$('#youRtabIDFor1').load(LoadSomeThingViaAjaxCall);
$('#youRtabIDFor2').load(LoadSomeThingViaAjaxCall);
```